# How can I use Java Mobile Phone's camera as a Webcam?

Tags: wireless, package-management, java, webcam, video-conversion

In windows there is a software called "Mobiola webcam" for use a mobile cam as a webcam . Is there any way for Linux (ubuntu 12.04 LTS) ?

Answer (score -1):

For Android you can use **Droidcam**.

[Here](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/07/turn-your-android-camera-into-wireless.html) is a nice tutorial how to install and configure in Ubuntu

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.